# PHP foreach nested table

Tags: php, foreach, html-table, nested

```
<table style="width: 600px" class="slicedTable">
     <tr>
      <th>Spetsialist</th>
      <th>Tunnid</th>
     </tr>


<tr>            
       <?php foreach($specs as $specName => $spec): ?>
        <td><?php echo $specName?>
        <tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>


<td>
        <?php foreach($tunnid as $tund): ?>
           <td><?php echo $tund?></td>

       </td>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

I need this to print out a regular table where it goes like:

name 1 - value1

 name2 - value2

Specs:

```
$specs = array();

            foreach($data as $row) {
                $workerName = $row['Worker']['name'];
                if (!isset($specs[$workerName])) {
                    $specs[$workerName] = array('procs' => array(), 'extras' => array());
                }
```

However I can't seem to accomplish this, help please.

Comment: Is `$spec` the "name" and `$tund` the "value"?

Comment: Why do you close the table 3 times?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Comment: Accidentally left it in, i tried two tables next to eachother from desperation.

Comment: What does your array look like?

Comment: What does the `$specs` array look like ?

Comment: added it in the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UPDATE*:
Seems like your arrays might have different lengths, so I updated the code below to handle such a situation (it doesn't matter which array is longer).

---

You could do it like this:

```
<table style="width: 600px" class="slicedTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Spetsialist</th>
        <th>Tunnid</th>
    </tr>
<?php $len1 = count($specs); $len2 = count($tunnid);
      $specsKeys = array_keys($specs);
      for ($i = 0; $i < max($len1, $len2); $i++) {
          $name  = ($i < $len1) ? $specsKeys[$i] : ""; 
          $value = ($i < $len2) ? $tunnid[$i] : ""; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo($name); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo($value); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/iQhlTC)** (**updated**).

Comment: If you take a look at the demo provided, you can see there is no error. The only reason I can think of to raise an error in your code would be if `$specs` and `$tunnid` don't have the same length or if you are using a variable named `$i` elsewhere in your code. In any case without the exact error (and code) I can't figure out what the problem in your code is.

Comment: @user2485439: Taking into account your comments in another answer it seems like your arrays might have different lengths. I know you have probably solved your problem by now, but in any case I updated my answer to be able to handle arrays of different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I fix for you:

Assuming the number of elements in `$spec` is same as or more than the number of elements in `$tunnid`. In coder's perspective, `count($spec) >= count($tunnid)`.

```
<table style="width: 600px" class="slicedTable">
   <tr>
      <th>Spetsialist</th>
      <th>Tunnid</th>
   </tr>
   <?php 
      $i = 0;
      foreach($specs as $specName => $spec): 
    ?>
   <tr>            
       <td><?php echo $specName; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo isset($tunnid[$i]) ? $tunnid[$i] : '-'; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
         $i++;
      endforeach; 
    ?>
 </table>
```

Not really an elegant solution, I admit.

Comment: but what if it's not? right now the table looks fine but the right values are next to eachother only when the number is the same.

Comment: If the number of elements in `$tunnid` is greater than number of elements in `$specs`, the remaining elements in `$tunnid` will not be shown.

Comment: okay, then there must be something wrong with my query, i'm not getting the right values next to the right names..

Comment: I updated the answer, now includes if `count($spec) >= count($tunnid)`.